# Human readable json in browser

Tags: json

I'm working on some webservice that returns data in JSON format.

I have `index.php` file that produces JSON. For debugging - I'm just open it in browser and I see JSON data without any indentation etc. I can paste that data here: http://iblogbox.com/devtools/myjson/ and I see pretty formatted JSON.

Is there any way to improve my productivity?

I have tried "JSON Formatter" addon for Chrome, but it does nothing, it is just link to web tool to website (link above).

Comment: Install a JSON pretty printer browser plugin (one that actually works)?

Comment: "JSON pretty printer" didn't worked for me. "JSONView" suggested by Zelldon works.

Comment: In the devtools console, you can use `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json), null, 2)` to get pretty-printed output. The third argument calls for printing-printing with two-space indentation.

Comment: JSON View works fine for me too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use JSONView, works fine for me:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc

Is also a chrome extension

Comment: I have tried few extensions and this is only one that worked.

Answer (score 2):

> **JSON_PRETTY_PRINT** (integer)
>   Use whitespace in returned data to format it. Available since PHP 5.4.0.

Specify this option in your PHP and you don't have to do a thing!

There are other useful options. See the [documentation](http://php.net/json-encode) for details. Personally, I like:

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
                      | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
                      | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: This is very interesting, but I'm using PHP 5.3 for now.

Comment: @Kamil Ah, I feel sorry for you XD 5.4 introduced a lot of awesome features. I'm on 5.6 myself.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to change PHP version on server with many services. My customers will kill me if some bad designed software stop working for some reason after I update PHP.

Comment: Consider moving your stuff to a virtual machine then? This way you can have whatever versions you want without affecting others.

Comment: Too much effort to get pretty JSON. I will think about it when there will be some more important reason to use PHP >5.3.